# PHP if else issue

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't get this if else to not break my page:

```
<?php
   $values = get_field('testimonial_text');
      if($values) {
      echo '                
      <div class="testimonial entry-content">
      <h2><?php the_field('testimonial_title'); ?></h2>
      <?php the_field('testimonial_text'); ?>
      </div>';
  } else {
       echo '';
      }
   ?>
```

Can someone show me what I did wrong and why what I did isn't working。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have nested `<?php .. ?>` blocks. That's a sign that something is wrong!

```
<?php
  $values = get_field('testimonial_text');
  if($values) {
    echo '<div class="testimonial entry-content">';
    echo '<h2>'; the_field('testimonial_title'); echo '</h2>';
    the_field('testimonial_text');
    echo '</div>';
  }
  // your else was a no-op, so I removed it
?>
```

Comment: @Jasper Except that said nested blocks contain single quotes, which exit out of the string.

Comment: Also you are using nested single-quotes. So if you really want a string containing a php tag (which is almost certainly not what you want) then at least escape those.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a PHP block within an already-open PHP block. That's just not going to work.